# Creating a PDF of version 1.5 and using the etexcmds-package

Tags: pdftex

When I compile this MWE:

```
\documentclass{report}
\pdfminorversion=5
\usepackage{etexcmds}
\begin{document}
Hi!
\end{document}
```

with `pdflatex` from TeXlive 2011, then I get in the log-file:

```
(.../etexcmds.sty
Package: etexcmds 2011/02/16 v1.5 Prefix for e-TeX command names (HO)

(.../infwarerr.sty
Package: infwarerr 2010/04/08 v1.3 Providing info/warning/message (HO)
)
(.../ifluatex.sty
Package: ifluatex 2010/03/01 v1.3 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
Package ifluatex Info: LuaTeX not detected.
)
Package etexcmds Info: Could not find \expanded.
(etexcmds)             That can mean that you are not using pdfTeX 1.50 or
(etexcmds)             that some package has redefined \expanded.
(etexcmds)             In the latter case, load this package earlier.
)
```

but Adobe Reader states at document properties: "PDF-Version: 1.5 (Acrobat 6.x)".
Is that some bug in `[etexcmds][1]`, or did I make some mistake?

Comment: You get a PDF1.5 file out: where is the issue?

Comment: Are you perhaps confusing pdfTeX v1.5 (a TeX binary: not released) with PDF1.5 (a PDF specification)?

Comment: @JosephWright: Uups! Yes. Well, shall I delete the question or leave it for other people making the same mistake?

Comment: You're confusing the version of PDF (1.5) and pdfTeX (1.40.12).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That info message is perfectly normal.

The current version of `pdftex` is 1.40 (it's independent of the PDF version); as far as I know an `\expanded` primitive was planned for `pdftex` version 1.50, but I don't know if it will ever see the light.

The package `etexcmds` checks for the existence of `\expanded` and doesn't find it as a primitive, so it tells you.

As of version 1.40, `pdftex` can output PDF 1.5 and setting `\pdfminorversion=5` does just that. However, this is the default as of TeX Live 2011 and, I believe, also MiKTeX 2.9.

Comment: OK, thanks, I confused pdftex version 1.50 and PDF version 1.5. Sorry!